# Show digital signature / certificate dialogs

Tags: c#, c, winapi

I have [*PKCS #7 SignedData*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387331.aspx) from an Authenticode-signed PE file. I want to show it in a dialog like this:

[image]

This is a standard Windows dialog, like you will see if you click **Details** on the **Digital Signatures** tab of a PE file.

Any idea how to do this?

I would prefer a C# solution, but the standard C API would also work (I could make a C++/CLI interface.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it took a lot of research, and a bit of reverse-engineering, but I eventually got it to work.

The magic function is [**`CryptUIDlgViewSignerInfo()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380291.aspx).

> The **CryptUIDlgViewSignerInfo** function displays a dialog box that contains the signer information for a signed message.

Unfortunately it, along with the definition for its only argument, [`CRYPTUI_VIEWSIGNERINFO_STRUCT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa380291.aspx) aren't in any header files.  So first you need to declare:

**CryptUI.h**

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

typedef struct tagCRYPTUI_VIEWSIGNERINFO_STRUCT {
  DWORD            dwSize;
  HWND             hwndParent;
  DWORD            dwFlags;
  LPCTSTR          szTitle;
  CMSG_SIGNER_INFO *pSignerInfo;
  HCRYPTMSG        hMsg;
  LPCSTR           pszOID;
  DWORD_PTR        dwReserved;
  DWORD            cStores;
  HCERTSTORE       *rghStores;
  DWORD            cPropSheetPages;
  LPCPROPSHEETPAGE rgPropSheetPages;
} CRYPTUI_VIEWSIGNERINFO_STRUCT, *PCRYPTUI_VIEWSIGNERINFO_STRUCT;



#ifdef UNICODE
#define CryptUIDlgViewSignerInfo CryptUIDlgViewSignerInfoW
#else
#define CryptUIDlgViewSignerInfo CryptUIDlgViewSignerInfoA
#endif

BOOL WINAPI CryptUIDlgViewSignerInfo(
  _In_  CRYPTUI_VIEWSIGNERINFO_STRUCT *pcvsi
);


#ifdef __cplusplus
}  // extern "C"
#endif
```

---

Now, this is a C++ CLI function, but it should easily work in plain C if you tweak the beginning. Of course, you'll want to do some better error checking as well, but this was just a proof-of-concept:

```
// Link against these libraries
#pragma comment (lib, "Crypt32")
#pragma comment (lib, "Cryptui")

void CertHelper::DoStuff(array<Byte>^ data) {

    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689154
    pin_ptr<Byte> pData = &data[0];

    CERT_BLOB blob;
    blob.cbData = data->Length;
    blob.pbData = pData;

    BOOL res;

    DWORD MsgAndCertEncodingType;
    DWORD ContentType;
    DWORD FormatType;
    HCERTSTORE hCertStore;
    HCRYPTMSG hMsg;

    res = CryptQueryObject(
        CERT_QUERY_OBJECT_BLOB,         // dwObjectType [in]
        &blob,                          // pvObject [in]
        CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_ALL,    // dwExpectedContentTypeFlags [in]
        CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_BINARY,  // dwExpectedFormatTypeFlags [in]
        0,                              // dwFlags [in]

        &MsgAndCertEncodingType,        // pdwMsgAndCertEncodingType [out]
        &ContentType,                   // pdwContentType [out]
        &FormatType,                    // pdwFormatType [out]
        &hCertStore,                    // phCertStore [out]
        &hMsg,                          // phMsg [out]
        NULL                            // ppvContext [out]
        );


    // Get the SignerInfo - call once to get size
    DWORD cb;

    res = CryptMsgGetParam(
        hMsg,                           // hCryptMsg [in]
        CMSG_SIGNER_INFO_PARAM,         // dwParamType [in]
        0,                              // dwIndex [in]
        NULL,                           // pvData [out]
        &cb                             // pcbData [in, out]
        );

    CMSG_SIGNER_INFO* signerinfo = (CMSG_SIGNER_INFO*)LocalAlloc(LPTR, cb);

    res = CryptMsgGetParam(
        hMsg,                           // hCryptMsg [in]
        CMSG_SIGNER_INFO_PARAM,         // dwParamType [in]
        0,                              // dwIndex [in]
        signerinfo,                     // pvData [out]
        &cb                             // pcbData [in, out]
        );


    // Initialize the View Signer Info structure
    CRYPTUI_VIEWSIGNERINFO_STRUCT vsi;
    memset(&vsi, 0, sizeof(vsi));
    vsi.dwSize = sizeof(vsi);
    vsi.hwndParent = NULL;  // TODO
    vsi.dwFlags = 0;    // SHDocvw.dll passes 0x14
    vsi.szTitle = NULL;
    vsi.pSignerInfo = signerinfo;
    vsi.hMsg = hMsg;
    vsi.pszOID = "1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3";   // XCN_OID_PKIX_KP_CODE_SIGNING


    // Show the dialog already!
    res = CryptUIDlgViewSignerInfo(&vsi);

    // Free resources
    LocalFree(signerinfo);
    if (hCertStore)   CertCloseStore(hCertStore, 0);
    if (hMsg)         CryptMsgClose(hMsg);
}
```

For reference sake, this was RE'd from `ViewCertProperties()` in `shdocvw.dll`.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the work leading up to the `CryptUIDlgViewSignerInfo` call seems to be already done internally by the .NET class [`System.Security.Cryptography.Pkcs.SignedCms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.pkcs.signedcms.aspx).

The two pieces required to populate the `CRYPTUI_VIEWSIGNERINFO_STRUCT` are already there, as private fields of `SignedCms`:

- `hMsg` is  `SignedCms.m_safeCryptMsgHandle`
- `pSignerInfo` is `SignerInfo.m_pbCmsgSignerInfo`

[image]

It would be incredible if we could just call a hypothetical `SignedCms.ShowSignerInfoDialog()` function, or somehow have access to these members without reflection.

The following hack does however work!

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var data = ...;

        var cms = new SignedCms();
        cms.Decode(data);

        var pbCmsgSignerInfo = typeof(SignerInfo).GetField("m_pbCmsgSignerInfo", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var si = (SafeHandle)pbCmsgSignerInfo.GetValue(cms.SignerInfos[0]);

        var safeCryptMessageHandle = typeof(SignedCms).GetField("m_safeCryptMsgHandle", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        var hMsg = (SafeHandle)safeCryptMessageHandle.GetValue(cms);

        var vsi = new CRYPTUI_VIEWSIGNERINFO_STRUCT {
            dwSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(CRYPTUI_VIEWSIGNERINFO_STRUCT)),
            pSignerInfo = si,
            hMsg = hMsg,
        };

        CryptUIDlgViewSignerInfo(ref vsi);
    }

    [DllImport("Cryptui.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool CryptUIDlgViewSignerInfo(ref CRYPTUI_VIEWSIGNERINFO_STRUCT pcvsi);
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
struct CRYPTUI_VIEWSIGNERINFO_STRUCT
{
    public UInt32 dwSize;
    public IntPtr hwndParent;
    public UInt32 dwFlags;
    public string szTitle;
    public SafeHandle pSignerInfo;
    public SafeHandle hMsg;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string pszOID;
    public IntPtr dwReserved;
    public UInt32 cStores;
    public IntPtr rghStores;
    public UInt32 cPropSheetPages;
    public IntPtr rgPropSheetPages;
}
```